# CouchDB error:When i run a view

Tags: couchdb

I installed `couchdb` on my VM

- vm version : Red Hat 4.4
- couchdb version : 1.6.1
- spidermonkey version : 1.8.5
- erlang version : R16B02

When I try to run a view, the log non-stop prints this error, just this message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suxJg.png)

Comment: The important information was in the image... It would have been far better to give it as a text (for better indexing).

Comment: `{os_process_error,{exit_status,127}}` means that [Spidermonkey installation is not correct](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages#OS_Process_Error_.7Bos_process_error.2C.7Bexit_status.2C127.7D.7D). We cannot assume much more from your question. Please note that for questions related to CouchDB installation rather than CouchDB use, you will have more chance to be helped on the [users mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/).

Comment: How to uninstall spidermonkey1.8.5?,I want reinstall, But I can't found packname,So I can't use rpm -e